# Why is a Java EE runtime Environment required for interpreting/parsing/compiling any code?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I imported an EAR project I had written on another system into eclipse so I had code before I had completely set up the GlassFish server environment and some other config files.

I noticed that even though I had a JDK and JRE integrated with my Eclipse environment it wasn't recognizing any library files like `javax`. This was preventing any kind of debugging until I had finished installing the runtime environment which for me was GlassFish 3.1.

I am confused about what all the runtime environment contains because I thought the libraries necessary to interpret my code in the IDE were in the JDK and WPT web tools that I had installed and not on the GlassFish server which I think of as "just a container and Java EE server".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java SE does not include the Java EE libraries.

There are non-Java EE `javax.*` packages in Java SE, however.

Comment: Thank you, and on a related question can you install these libraries without having to install glassfish.  This seems like something that would come up with developers who are writing code without necessarily deploying on a server immediately or locally. Am I right?

Comment: You can add the API jars to your project.  It is a bit cumbersome to hunt them down.

Comment: All you need are the APIs, not an actual implementation. That said, most JEE devs have at least a web server installed locally, if not an app server.

Comment: weird, I guess you could program some EJB's as POJO's without annotating them as session beans and it wouldn't make sense to ever create a servlet outside of a setting where you could make HTTPrequest calls, the same with database programming. They're just too interrelated.

Comment: @user988231 That's what I mean--most everyone will have an environment in which to run their code, but you don't need a runtime environment to compile.